# How do I download non-dataframe data from a Databricks notebook?

Tags: python, databricks

I'm trying to download a schema of a dataframe, or essentially the output of `df.printSchema()` but the schema is too big that it's getting truncated in the output.
This is in a production environment too, so I can't temporarily store the output onto the Hive metastore. Any way to fully print or save the output of printSchema()?

Comment: Is it literally that you’re trying to get `printSchema()` to print fully/completely to a notebook in Databricks? Are you trying to use the code in your notebook to write it to a file on a filesystem somewhere? What’s your ultimate goal using this information?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but what comes to my mind is that you could:

1. Store the schema print to Python variable

   `schema_str = df._jdf.schema().treeString()`
2. Mount storage to Databricks workspace like in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/mounts)

   ```
   container_name = ""
   storage_account_name = ""
   conf_key = f"fs.azure.account.key.{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net"
   dbutils.fs.mount(
     source = f"wasbs://{container_name}@{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net",
     mount_point = "/mnt/schema_prints",
     extra_configs = {conf_key:<blob_secret>}
   )
   ```
3. Store string to the mounted storage

```
with open("/mnt/schema_prints/schema_{id}.txt", "w") as f:
   f.write(schema_str)
```

I hope this answers your question!